# SharePoint 2013: Solution or App?

Tags: 2013, workflow, app, solution

Hej there

I have been developing some SP2007 and 2010 solutions in the past but got a new project a customer requested. A approval and publishing process for a specific type of word document (some attachments should be linked to this document too) should be ported to SharePoint 2013 (new clean installation, no SharePoint installed until now). The document should go through three approval processes until it gets published.

My plan is to create a new content type based on DOCUMENT with new site columns for the custom fields. A workflow should do the whole approval and publishing thing. Custom UI could be neccessary.

How should I implement this in SP2013? Should I create a new solution as I would for SP2010, containing the definitions of the content type, lists, workflow and finally a GUI?

I'm not sure that a (SP hosted-) App would be the right way. The list definitions, content type and everything would be totally independent from the SP platform. But these documents should be persistent!

Any experience in this type of problems yet?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create all of the mentioned artifacts content type, lists, workflow and GUI in SharePoint Hosted apps. But remember that you have to perform all your coding using REST and/or javascript client object model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does it make sense to have all these artifacts in one single app? 
After removing the app from SP, will the lists still be there?

Comment: When a SahrePoint Hosted app is installed it creates a subsite known as app web. All of these artifacts will stay inside it. When you uinstall/remove an app, the app web will be deleted and everything will be lost.

Comment: So this is still best practice? It's quite dangerous to loose all these documents. Is there a better way? Should I create the lists containing the documents manually in Sharepoint and access them in the app to make sure that they stay if anyone removes the app?

Comment: stick with farm solutions as far as you can, based on my own opinion.

Comment: In that case you will need to create content types/lists etc in host web. But that can become tedious to code as you cannot use declarative markup. Everything will need to be provisioned using code. The basic idea of apps is to keep minimum/no footprint when they are uninstalled.